# Get a specific ListBox item

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone, listboxitem

On my Windows Phone App, have a ListBox populated from JSON (webservice).
I need test if a string is equal to some item on ListBox. But I "binding" many informations, and I want test only with `{Binding codigo}`.

This code not works for me:

```
private void addProduto(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Fields fi = (Fields)this.List1.SelectedItem as Fields;

        foreach(var item in List1.Items)
        {
            Fields fields = item as Fields;
            if (fields.codigo == insCodProduto.Text)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Esse produto existe!");

            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Esse produto não existe!");
                break;
            }

        }
```

My code:

```
public ObservableCollection<Fields> Items { get; set; }

public class Fields
    {

        //[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "descricao")]
        public string descricao { get; set; }
        public double valor_preco_a { get; set; }
        public string codigo { get; set; }
        public string codigo1 { get; set; }


    }
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="List1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="0,85,0,0" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="242" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="128" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,-62,17" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                                    <StackPanel.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF858585" Opacity="0.5"/>
                                    </StackPanel.Background>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="NameTxt" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding descricao}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding valor_preco_a, StringFormat=N2}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="45,20,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding codigo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="35" Margin="370,-50,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Foreground="Blue"/>

                                </StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="R$" Margin="15,48,158,17" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListBox>
```

insCodProduto:

```
<TextBox InputScope="Number" x:Name="insCodProduto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="161" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="262,152,0,0" Height="78"/>
```

Comment: I've updated the answer. Hope it'll work now

Answer (score 1):

Cast your item to `Fields` class first. Now you have access to properties inside

```
Fields fields = item as Fields;

if (fields.descricao == insCodProduto.Text)
{
    //do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Put it into foreach, where item will be current item in loop

Comment: the code is within of the foreach. I edited my question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast every `List Item` to get specific value from it:

```
foreach(Fields item in List1.Items) //casting listbox item to "Fields"
{
    if(item.codigo.ToString() == insCodProduto.Text)    //codigo is int type so you'll have to convert it to string
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ok");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why, but your example and the example of @Ku6opr works for first item of the ListBox. Only for "1" position, for other positions (to 65 position).

Comment: Can you explain again what do you want to achieve? I think there is some misunderstanding

Comment: My ListBox has 65 items currently. Each of these has one code ({Binding codigo}). I need validate if the number inserted by the user exists on my ListBox.

Comment: The answer is appropriate according to your issue. It should work. You need to do some debugging on the `foreach loop` iterations and you'll find the problem.

Comment: If I insert "code 2", the test jumps to "else" (says not exists). If I insert "code 1", the test says exists. For all codes different of "1", not work. I debugged the code, but not understand why. :(

Comment: Show me some more code. What is `insCodProduto` and how does it's value set?